# How to ensure my videos will not play outside of my Android app?

Tags: android, video, copy-protection

In my application there are 3 videos, I want to play videos in only my application, I want to protect that videos, prevent to show and play videos from FileExplorer and Gallery.

I tried Encryption and Decryption methods, I stored video with Encryption but when I play that video first I decrypt video and then play but in this case decryption process is very large so user must waiting for long-time.

Answer (score 2):

Store your video with some odd extension and at the time of loading that video in your application change to the original extension.

[image]

Here Pani_-myEdit.myext is the renamed video file with .myext extension and it shows the above option

Comment: If user is un-aware for this then he can easily delete these files. Because He thinks, files are Unnecessary..

Comment: that can be the cause, for something to get you have to loose somthing,
try making an app named folder to store that videos so user can have some idea that these files are related to this app. Got my point

Comment: file Explorer and gallery supports few file extensions so if you have an extension like .myext then Explorer and gallery will not show that file. I have just tried this in my device right now.

Comment: File with other axtension and without extension file with FileExplorer openWith VideoPlayer. so video is play with InBuilt MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

For providing strong security of your video files **Encryption-Decryption** is necessary. There is no other way to prevent other applications or user to access them from device. But this process is big hit on performance of accessing those files.

If you store your video files in `/asset` directory then there is possibility of accessing those file by extracting `.apk` file as a `zip`.

Also Even internal storage of application package `/data/data/<package_name>/files` is not a safe for store those files, some File-Explorer and root permission of devices access them easily.

Comment: one problem with this stuff is, if that videos are of more than 50 MB, he could not upload that apk on market

Comment: Ok this is perfect. but in future i have many videos more than 200. and Video size is very large. so my apk size exceed 50 MB. so i wanto to store that videos on SDCARD. In this case how to prevent my Videos from another access.

Comment: Then Encryption-Decryption is the only way I think..

Comment: simple store that video in app named folder on sdcard with odd extension. In other way you are also right but i think it would be expensive.

Comment: Ok I got it I store my video file with Encryption and store on SDCARD but when i play that file first of all i decrypt that file and play that file so it is time consuming.

Comment: In my suggestion NO. If you want to go with other answer then be careful some FileExplorer display all file list of device with any extension. And if you want to store video in asset then third party video player can't play those files.

Comment: @user370305 - actually, that's untrue.  The apk file itself tends to be readable on devices these days, which means that the contents of the assets folder are extractable if someone figures out to look there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Yes, I know,.apk file is one type of zip file in which you can get the data from it by extract it. So it also not a feasible solution. Only Enceryption-Decryption is way.

Comment: But i put my all videos in data/data/packagename/folder, then nobody can see my videos but one problem is there i can not put more videos more than phone internal memory.

Comment: Yes, the same case possible in /asset directory also. For more space you have to use external storage. Also if any root device installed your app then it can easily access these videos.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such way if you want to store your files on sd card.. the videos will be visible..
even if they are in your data folder.. it is viewable from the file explorer.
and if you are including videos in your asset folder then they are not visible even to your file explorer...
`Encryption-Decryption` is an expensive way for hiding files.

`use asset folder` in your android project

Answer (score 1):

Willing to decrypt the entire video before to start playing exposes the user to a noticeable delay.
You should explore a [streaming solution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer) to avoid this problem.